# custom template for categories?

Tags: category, template

Possible to add custom templates to one or multiple category?

Also tried to add custom .phtml file to

```
/app/design/frontend/flatshop/default/template/category/
```

with different names, but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

First create a new folder `/app/design/frontend/flatshop/your-special-style/template/category/`...

Edit your Category:
Manage Category => Select Category => Tab "Custom Design" => Choose your new Design (DropDown "Custom Design") - e. g. your-special-style

After that you just need to do an override, e. g. copy

```
./app/design/frontend/flatshop/default/template/category/view.phtml
```

to

```
./app/design/frontend/flatshop/your-special-style/template/category/view.phtml
```